# ChartJS custom tooltip doesn't render background on labels (only the title)

Tags: chart.js

Using ChartJS, I want to be able to change the title on a tooltip depending on the data (mainly as I want the text in a smaller font size than the label). I don't really need a full custom HTML tooltip, just be able to change fontsize and title text.

However just setting this via a "custom" callback means the label for the dataset doesn't have the background correctly displayed

```
options: {
    tooltips: {         
        custom : t => {
            t.title = ['Hello'];        
        }
    }
}
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPurpleStreak/2n8md9Lh/

Hover over a point and see the "hello" on a black background, but the data not.

NOTE: I've found a way to accomplish my initial goal, but this struck me as a bug in chartJS?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the custom property.

I recommend using the `callbacks` instead :

```
tooltips: {
    displayColors: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0,1)',
    callbacks: {
      title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
        return 'Hello';
      },
    }
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n8md9Lh/25/)

Comment: Thanks - that was indeed my workaround and I use the `custom` bit just to change the title color to be the same.  I'll post the issue to Chart.JS